# Table Not Showing Responsive

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

In my HTML Table below why am I not getting the responsive look even though the class is set?

**Code:**

```
<html class="no-js" lang="" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>
      Table Design
    </title>
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u"
    crossorigin="anonymous" type="text/css" />
    <style type="text/css">
    blockquote p{font-size: 12px;}
    .removeTop{border-top: none !important;}
    </style>
    </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="center-block">
      <h1 class="page-header">
        Term 1 2017
      </h1>
      <table class="table table-responsive">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Location</th>
            <th>Group</th>
            <th>Day</th>
            <th>Time</th>
            <th>Cost</th>
            <th></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Point Chevalier</td>
            <td>Cruisers</td>
            <td>Tuesday</td>
            <td>10:00</td>
            <td>$149.50</td>
            <td><img class="alignnone" src="http://website.co.nz/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/book-btn.png" alt="book-btn" width="121" height="30" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Point Chevalier</td>
            <td>Movers</td>
            <td>Tuesday</td>
            <td>11:15</td>
            <td>$149.50</td>
            <td><img class="alignnone" src="http://website.co.nz/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/book-btn.png" alt="book-btn" width="121" height="30" /></td>
          </tr>
        <tr class="block">
            <td class="removeTop"></td>
            <td class="removeTop"></td>
            <td class="removeTop"></td>
            <td class="removeTop"></td>
            <td class="removeTop"></td>
            <td class="removeTop"></td>
            <td class="removeTop"></td>
          </tr>
              <tr>
            <td>Point Chevalier</td>
            <td>Groovers</td>
            <td>Wednesday</td>
            <td>9:45</td>
            <td>$149.50</td>
            <td><img class="alignnone" src="http://website.co.nz/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/book-btn.png" alt="book-btn" width="121" height="30" /></td>
          </tr>
                        <tr>
            <td>Point Chevalier</td>
            <td>Cruisers</td>
            <td>Wednesday</td>
            <td>11:00</td>
            <td>$149.50</td>
            <td><img class="alignnone" src="http://website.co.nz/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/book-btn.png" alt="book-btn" width="121" height="30" /></td>
          </tr>
                        <tr>
            <td>Point Chevalier</td>
            <td>Movers</td>
            <td>Wednesday</td>
            <td>12:15</td>
            <td>$149.50</td>
            <td><img class="alignnone" src="http://website.co.nz/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/book-btn.png" alt="book-btn" width="121" height="30" /></td>
          </tr>
        <tr class="block">
            <td class="removeTop"></td>
            <td class="removeTop"></td>
            <td class="removeTop"></td>
            <td class="removeTop"></td>
            <td class="removeTop"></td>
            <td class="removeTop"></td>
            <td class="removeTop"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>St Heliers</td>
            <td>Groovers</td>
            <td>Friday</td>
            <td>9:45</td>
            <td>$149.50</td>
            <td><img class="alignnone" src="http://website.co.nz/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/book-btn.png" alt="book-btn" width="121" height="30" /></td>
          </tr>
                                  <tr>
            <td>St Heliers</td>
            <td>Cruisers</td>
            <td>Friday</td>
            <td>11:00</td>
            <td>$149.50</td>
            <td><img class="alignnone" src="http://website.co.nz/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/book-btn.png" alt="book-btn" width="121" height="30" /></td>
          </tr>
                                  <tr>
            <td>St Heliers</td>
            <td>Movers</td>
            <td>Friday</td>
            <td>12:15</td>
            <td>$149.50</td>
            <td><img class="alignnone" src="http://website.co.nz/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/book-btn.png" alt="book-btn" width="121" height="30" /></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>

      </table>       
       <caption>
          <strong>Monday - New Central Auckland location to be announced soon</strong>
        </caption>
      <div class="row">

        <div> 
        <blockquote>
          <p>Book now, Pay Later *conditions apply</p>
          <p>20% deposit required, this is non-refundable if you pull out before term time commences</p>
          <p>*Remainder of payment due in January 2017</p>
      </blockquote>
      </div>
      <div>
      <blockquote>
        <p><strong>Pt Chevalier</strong> - Tuesday 7th Feb - Tuesday 11th April (10 week term)</p>
        <p><strong>Pt Chevalier</strong> - Wednesday 8th Feb - Wednesday 12th April (10 week term)</p>
        <p><strong>St Heliers</strong> - Friday 3rd Feb - Friday 7th April (10 week term)</p>
      </blockquote>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You added the `table-responsive` class to the `table` tag.

To make your table responsive in bootstrap. Wrap your table with a `div`.

```
<div class="table-responsive" >
   <table class="table">
      ...
   </table>
</div>
```

I think that will fix your problem.